# Convert Contents of Div Tag into Image format

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am a Software Trainee in asp.net.

This is my div tag.

```
<div id="contentsDiv">
    <b>Write some thing</b>
    <br/><br>
    <img alt="Koala" src="Images/Koala.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
    <br< /><br>
    <i>Some thing means any thing </i>
</div>



<asp:Button ID="Export" runat="server" Text="Export" onclick="Export_Click" />
```

Now,On click of Export button ,I want to convert the contents of tag into an image and save that image in particular folder.

Answer (score 1):

To convert content of html into an image is something not really easy.. but i think you can do this

```
 class Program
    {
         [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var bmp = MakeScreenshot(@"<div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>");

            bmp.Save(@"c:\pdf\test.jpg");
        }


        public static Bitmap MakeScreenshot(string html)
        {
            // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Navigate("about:blank");
            if (wb.Document != null)
            {

                wb.Document.Write(html);

            }

            wb.DocumentText = html;

            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            //      wb.Navigate(this.Uri);
            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }


            // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
                // Take Screenshot of the web pages full width
                wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
                // Take Screenshot of the web pages full height
                wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;

            if (wb.Height <= 0)
            {
                wb.Height = 768;
            }

            // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
            wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
            wb.Dispose();

            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is showing some error ,please tell me on which file this code has to be written ie.fileName.aspx.cs or fileName.cs

Answer (score 0):

Please give us some more details about your webapp and the goal want to achive. You probably mean client-side export, but I can't be 100% sure.

If this is the case, you can draw this div into a canvas element, then use the `HTMLCanvasElement` object's `toDataURL` to allow user saving via browser 'closed' div content.

```
var c = document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id');
var t = c.getContext('2d');
```

When the user clicks "Export", do this:

```
window.open('', document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id').toDataURL());
```

More info in [`Canvas tutorial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial) and [this blog](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/)

It is quite difficult task for a Software Trainee :).